# Posting a 311 Movement Through API_MATERIAL_DOCUMENT_SRV

Tags: s4sdk

I am trying to move inventory from unrestricted to blocked stock using an API.  The  API I am using is API_MATERIAL_DOCUMENT_SRV.  I am getting the following error:

"Field InventoryStockType cannot be set for this operation on item level"

The message I am posting through Postman is the following:

```
{
"PostingDate": "2018-08-14T00:00:00",
"GoodsMovementCode": "01",
"to_MaterialDocumentItem": [{
  "Material": "MZ-FG-E11",
  "Plant": "1710",
  "StorageLocation": "171A",
  "GoodsMovementType": "311",
  "Batch" : "0000000001",
  "InventoryStockType": "01",
  "EntryUnit": "PC",
  "QuantityInEntryUnit": "11",
  "IssuingOrReceivingStockType":"02",
  "IssgOrRcvgMaterial":"MZ-FG-E11",
  "IssgOrRcvgBatch":"0000000001",
  "IssuingOrReceivingPlant":"1710",
  "IssuingOrReceivingStorageLoc":"171A"
  }]
}
```

Can anyone advise on what this message should look like?

Comment: Can you please additionally provide the whole request (excluding confidential parts, of course)? Especially the HTTP method as well as the endpoint you used.

Comment: Hi Goodman Darren, can you pls provide the details requested by Christoph or update this question with an answer, given you managed to solve that yourself? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use a 344 for this:

```js
{
"PostingDate": "2018-08-14T00:00:00",
"GoodsMovementCode": "04",
"to_MaterialDocumentItem": [{
  "Material": "MZ-FG-E11",
  "Plant": "1710",
  "StorageLocation": "171A",
  "GoodsMovementType": "344",
  "Batch" : "0000000001",
  "QuantityInEntryUnit": "11",
  "IssuingOrReceivingStorageLoc":"171A"

  
  
  }]
}
```